# Inverse of Fredholm convolution operator

Tags: analysis, operator-theory

If we consider operator $I-T$,while
$$T(f)(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}k(x-y)f(t)dt$$
while$$k(x)=ae^{ix^2},a \in \mathbb{C}$$
is the Fredholm convolution operator.
Question:is $I-T$ invertible? is $(I-T)^{-1}$ a compact operator?
Thanks for your answear.

Comment: What space does $T$ act on? Also it looks like your integral has a typo.

It might be helpful to know that if $T:V\to V$ is a bounded linear operator on a a Banach space $V$, then it's injective if its kernel is trivial and it's surjective if there's a $\delta>0$ such that $\Vert Tf\Vert \ge \delta \Vert f \Vert
$ for all $f\in V$.

Comment: $T$ act on $L^{2}[-1,1]$

Comment: You should edit your question to add that information, as well as any conditions you have on $k$. Maybe you can check the conditions I gave you.

Comment: @user27182: your second condition is equivalent to closed range, not to surjectivity.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I missed out that it's $T^*$ that needs to be bounded below but, provided that's added, I think what I said is contained in Theorem 4.13 of Rudin, Functional Analysis. (Please tell me if you still think I've made an error)

Comment: Yes, if $T^*$ is bounded below then it is injective and it has closed range, which implies that $T$ is surjective.